# Optional queries in Gatsby / GraphQL

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have a Gatsby site with a contentful source, the initial page build GraphQL looks like this:

```
{
    allContentfulProduct {
        edges {
            node {
                slug
                contentfulid
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this works fine when using the preview API, but when using the production one it fails unless I have at least 1 `Product` entry published:

```
There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Cannot query field "allContentfulProduct" on type "Query". Did you mean ... [suggested entry names] ?
```

I'm pretty sure that when I publish a `Product` things will work as expected, but is there any way to make this query optional. The query should return zero results, and thus no `Product` pages will be created (expected outcome if no `Product` entries are published)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add into your `gatsby-node.js` file and play around that.

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = `
       type allContentfulProduct implements Node{
       slug: String,
       contentfulid: String
  }`
```